# How to pass in production mode my node JS application (backend + frontend with Vue3 & typescript) using pm2 and nginx?

Tags: typescript, nginx, vuejs3, vite, production

I have a production server where I want to set up my app in production mode.
I have done a separate back and front application.
I'm using pm2 to run my backend.

I have enabled two configurations for nginx.

```
sudo touch /etc/nginx/sites-available/bioinfoweb.conf
sudo touch /etc/nginx/sites-available/api.bioinfoweb.conf

sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/api.bioinfoweb.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/api.bioinfoweb.conf
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/bioinfoweb.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/bioinfoweb.conf
```

The back is built using :

> tsc --project tsconfig.json

From this I got an app.js , I can run with

> pm2 start ./dist/app.js

The front (Vue3 based) is built using :

> vite build

The dist directory (from front built) is used to create a symbolic dir to /var/www/

```
sudo ln -s ./dist /var/www/SignalR_front/
sudo chmod -R 755/var/www/SignalR_front/
```

The configuration of nginx is as follows :

```
# BACKEND api.bioinfoweb.conf
server {
   server_name 1.2.3.4;
   location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}

# FRONT bioinfoweb.conf
server {
   server_name 1.2.3.4;
   location /front/ {
        root /var/www/SignalR_front/dist;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5173;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

My backend is working fine.
But I'm not succeeding in having both front and back working together and I think this is in part due to a bad configuration of nginx.

It would have been nice to have the back been handled by pm2. I read that pm2 was not advised for production with transpilers.   So they recommand to use ts-node to get app.js...

Vite build is a fast solution to get the front built but then I'm not able to run pm2 with it. (you end up with index.html) and I don't know how to tell nginx to read it.

Nginx is runing (I get the hello word).
When Nginx is closed, vite preview --host --port 5173 display the front.

These ports are open :

> Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
> 22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
> 80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                   443
> ALLOW       Anywhere                   5173
> ALLOW       Anywhere                   Nginx HTTP (v6)
> ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              22/tcp (v6)
> ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              80/tcp (v6)
> ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              443 (v6)
> ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              5173 (v6)
> ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

**UPDATE1 :**

I removed the symlink in /var/www/ and I directly paste the dir and change the bioinfo.web.conf. It works for the front. Let see the backend now. Ok I changed the location for the backend from /api to /

This works but I would prefer to have the front using port 80

## FRONT

server {
listen    5173;
server_name 1.1.1.1.1;
charset utf-8;
root    /var/www/SignalR;
location / {
autoindex off;
root /var/www/SignalR;
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
index index.html;

```
}
error_log  /var/log/nginx/vue-app-error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/vue-app-access.log;
```

}

## API

server {
server_name 1.1.1.1.1;
location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
error_log  /var/log/nginx/api-app-error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/api-app-access.log;
}